# resize Google Charts from external JS

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am using google charts and realize it doesn't have the option to automatically fit the parent when window is resized.

Found some answers here and this works if the google chart is on inline HTML. 
This is my inline HTML JS script.

```
<script>
            google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBarChart);
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLineChart);

            function drawLineChart(){
                // Define the chart to be drawn.
              var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();


              var timeStamp = [{% for item in labels %}
                             new Date("{{item}}"),
                            {% endfor %}]
              var speed = [{% for item in values.speed %}
                              {{item}},
                            {% endfor %}];
              var soc = [{% for item in values.soc %}
                              {{item}},
                            {% endfor %}];
              var dataArray = [];

              for (i=0;i<timeStamp.length;i++){
                var tempArray = []
                tempArray.push(timeStamp[i])
                tempArray.push(speed[i])
                tempArray.push(soc[i])
                dataArray.push(tempArray)
              }


              data.addColumn('datetime', 'Time of Day');
              data.addColumn('number', 'Speed');
              data.addColumn('number', 'SOC');
              data.addRows(dataArray);

              var options  = {
                legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 }
              }

              // Instantiate and draw the chart.
              var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("lineChart"));
              console.log("chart: ", chart);
              chart.draw(data, options);

            }



          $(window).resize(function(){
            drawBarChart();
            drawLineChart();
          });

</script>
```

Now, my question would be, I have a button that would dynamically change the data on the charts, but they are on an external JS script. It works, the charts are changing dynamically, but when I resize, the charts will display the first set of data when the page was first visited instead of the new data fetch when the button is clicked. How do I go about resizing the charts?

Here is the external JS Script.

```
$(function() {

  function getResult(timeRange){
    return $.ajax({
      url: "/vehicles/"+ $("#vehicle-name").text() + "/" + timeRange
    });
  }

  function displayCards(energy, mileage) {
    $("#energy").text(energy).hide().fadeIn();
    $("#mileage").text(mileage).hide().fadeIn();
  }

  function drawLineChart(values, labels){
      // Define the chart to be drawn.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    console.log(values);

    var speed = values.speed;
    var soc = values.soc;
    var dataArray = [];

    for (i=0;i<labels.length;i++){
      var tempArray = []
      tempArray.push(new Date(labels[i]))
      tempArray.push(speed[i])
      tempArray.push(soc[i])
      dataArray.push(tempArray)
    }

    console.log(dataArray);
    data.addColumn('datetime', 'Time of Day');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Speed');
    data.addColumn('number', 'SOC');
    data.addRows(dataArray);

    var options  = {
      legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 }
    }

    // Instantiate and draw the chart.
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("lineChart"));
    console.log("chart: ", chart);
    chart.draw(data, options);

  }

  $("#six_hour").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    getResult("sixhour").done(function(data) {
      let labels = data.time_stamp;
      let values = data.values;
      drawLineChart(values, labels);
    });

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `let` make your variable `labels` and `values` localized. And thus you can no longer retrieve the new data when you resize it.

There are many way to solve it, I am not sure what your preference. However, for convenient, I prefer to find a place saving the data I want instead calling everytime.

I will create a place to hold my data, so I can ref for when I resize.

```
var data_obj = new Object();

($(function()
...//other code

$("#six_hour").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    data_obj.current_button = 'six_hour';
    if (!("sixhour" in data_obj)){
      getResult("sixhour").done(function(data) {
        let labels = data.time_stamp;
        let values = data.values;
        data_obj.six_hour = {labels: labels, values:values}

    });}
    drawLineChart(data_obj.six_hour.values, data_obj.six_hour.labels);
})

$(window).resize(function(){

       drawLineChart(data_obj[data_obj.current_button].values, data_obj[data_obj.current_button].labels);
   });
})
```

Besides, I dun think it is good idea to redraw the graph everytime you resize. Indeed if your data size is bulky, it will lag. Try define some range of size to do this, like if windows size < 1000, then redraw, etc.

**Update 13/6/2018**

I figure out that I do make some typo after I really write it.... Though I originally think providing the idea is pretty enough....

I write a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MatrixTai/ovhjt4ga/), you can see **after clicking button**, you can resize the chart using new data.

If you dun want to cache the data, just simply remove the 'six_hour' tag in the object, using like

```
data_obj = {labels: labels, values:values}
```

instead of

```
data_obj.six_hour = {labels: labels, values:values}
```

And also remove `if (!("sixhour" in data_obj))`

Comment: I don't think you can access the values and labels on resize, because on the six_hour click function, you assign them to "sixhour" key. right?

Comment: with every click of the button, the data might really change so if the "sixhour" is already in the object, it can't retrieve new data. the getResult func actually queries the database for new records.

Comment: @essramos you are right, I originally didn't add a way to reduce duplicate ajax call everytime click. I forget to change the code in resize function. Updated.

Comment: thanks for the update, but this still doesn't allow getFunction to retrieve data oncee the six_hour key is already there. And also I tried this, but still same effects, the resize still follows the first set of data when page is first loaded.

Comment: @essramos Okay, I wrote a jsfiddle for you, take a look if have further problem.

Comment: great, this works, sorry you had to be specific but I get the idea of what you wanted to happen! :)